# Save user Auth Details from Clientside with Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm building a project in Vue, and I have Auth working on front end, but now I want to save some user data on Firebase Database and I am not sure how to do that using functions since I am doing a server-less backend.

I tried to find an example on how to be able to pass data from client-side to functions api but I couldn't find any.

Looking forward to receive any help from someone,
Regards,
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase provides you a REST api to do this, check out their documentation in this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data).